# How to exit node process with many sychronous Sequelize calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have some code that looks something like below.

```
Post.findAll(){
.then(function (posts) {
    var i;

    for (i in posts) {

        Comment.findAll({where: {post_id: posts[i].id}}){
        .then(function (comments) {
            // do some stuff.

            return;
        });
    }

    return;
});
```

It runs, but never exits. The `Comment` calls can just all run sychronously. Normally I will run things in order so there will be a series of `return` calls. But in this case it doesn't matter. The process just hangs and never exits out. It's a cron job so I need it to exit after firing off all the calls.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not calling `Sequelize::close`. Therefore the connection remains open (possibly until some timeout) and so the process does not terminate.

From lib/sequelize.js:

```
/**
 * Close all connections used by this sequelize instance, and free all references so the instance can be garbage collected.
 *
 * Normally this is done on process exit, so you only need to call this method if you are creating multiple instances, and want
 * to garbage collect some of them.
 */
Sequelize.prototype.close = function () {
  this.connectionManager.close();
};
```

I have some tests [here](https://github.com/cfogelberg/sequelize-playground) that demonstrate this:

- `tests/00-demo/run.sh` - terminates correctly
- `tests/01-demo-no-close/run.sh` - call to close() commented out, hangs